# what is '-' in man throttle command example

Tags: linux, tar

Excuse me if this sounds pretty noobie.
I was just checking the man page for throttle about how does the pipeline work hand in hand for throttle.
So while checking the manual page example, I stuck over '-' in the below command.
In there manual page in the EXAMPLE section, the first example was as follows:

```
   To limit the bandwidth of a tar back-up to a remote server to 1 Mbit/s, type:

   $ tar czf - . | throttle -m 1 | ssh host 'tar xzf - -C /bak'
```

Now in here, I wanted to understand the '-' just after czf and '-' after xzf.
If this doubt is clear, I would be comfortable to understand the whole command.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll break down the command into pieces and explain it piece by piece:

```
tar czf - .
```

This command tells `tar` to create an archive from current directory, and save the output to file indicated by `-f` argument. Here the file is `-`, which means standard output.

The `|` character takes standard output from left side command and passes it as standard input to the right side command.

In this case, the output of `tar` is passed as input to `throttle -m 1`, which then provides the output to last command:

```
ssh host 'tar xzf - -C /bak'
```

Output is piped via SSH to `tar` command running on `host`, using SSH as pipe transport. The `xzf -` argument means that `tar` reads from standard input and extracts the archive. Before extraction, `tar` changes to `/bak` directory.

As a summary, when creating archive, the `-f -` means that tar outputs the result to standard output (stdout).

When extracting archive, the `-f -` means that tar reads the input archive from standard input (stdin).

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part to look at is really `-f -` (the `-` in your question is the parameter to the `-f` option, specifying the filename)

What this says is to read from/write to the file `-`, which is a common special case for filenames. `-` in this context commonly means stdin (when reading) or stdout when writing.

Ie, the first `tar` process writes an archive to stdout, which is then piped through `throttle`, and then piped to the second `tar` process which reads an archive from stdin.